# How to enter SELECTED checkbox values in database using C#, SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have set of 10 checkbox on my form. Each checkbox has its own column in the database table.

When the user clicks on some checkbox, the selected checkbox value must be inserted into its column in the database table. Any idea how I can do that?

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work. Only first checkbox value is inserted into its own column, other columns are unaffected.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection cnm = new SqlConnection(connStr);

     cnm.Open();

     if (CheckBox1.Checked)
     {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO services(artist) VALUES (@artist)", cnm);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artist", CheckBox1.Checked);
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
     }
     else if (CheckBox2.Checked)
     {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO services(apprepair) VALUES (@apprepair)", cnm);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apprepair", CheckBox2.Checked);
            cmd1.ExecuteReader();
     }
}
```

Here's the asp.net markup:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-family:Muli, sans-serif;">
        <div class="form-check">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
            <label class="form-check-label" style="color:rgb(255,15,15);font-size:20px;" formmethod="post">Artist and Fine Arts&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-check">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"/>
            <label class="form-check-label" style="color:rgb(36,0,255);font-family:Muli, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">Appliance Repair</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-check">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server"/>
            <label class="form-check-label" runat="server" style="color:rgb(255,0,0);font-family:Muli, sans-serif;font-size:20px;"> Service and Repairs</label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-check">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server"/>
            <label class="form-check-label" runat="server" style="color:rgb(20,0,255);font-family:Muli, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">Carpenter&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-check">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server"/>
            <label class="form-check-label"  style="color:rgb(255,0,0);font-family:Muli, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">Electrical and Electronics&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-check">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server"/>
             <label class="form-check-label"  style="color:rgb(51,0,255);font-family:Muli, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">I.T Solutions&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

.... and so on and so forth ........

Answer (score 1):

Set field names into Tag of your checkboxes, for example set "artist" into Tag of CheckBox1 then write to your button click:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
    if (control is CheckBox)
    {            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO services({(control as CheckBox).Tag.ToString()}) VALUES (@a)", cnm);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", (control as CheckBox).Checked);
        cmd.ExecuteReader();        
}
```

Comment: $ used in VS2017.

Comment: can you please justify the code more , like how to use it for 4 or more checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not with the SQL But with your C# Code.

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO services(artist) VALUES (@artist)", cnm);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artist", CheckBox1.Checked);
            cmd.ExecuteReader();

        }

        **else if (CheckBox2.Checked)-- Issue is Here**
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO services(apprepair) VALUES (@apprepair)", cnm);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apprepair", CheckBox2.Checked);
            cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

In the 2nd If, you are using `Else if` so If the 1st Checkbox is checked then the remaining conditions won't be executed. Instead, you may use only `IF` instead of `ELSE IF`

**OR**

You Can Directly use the following Approach.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO services(artist) VALUES (@artist)", cnm);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artist", CheckBox1.Checked);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); -- Since Insert Statement Wont have any Retun values, Use ExecuteNonQuery

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO services(apprepair) VALUES (@apprepair)", cnm);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apprepair", CheckBox2.Checked);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```